# Hosting java/j2ee web app on tomcat6 along with mysql5.1 database

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, amazon-ec2, tomcat6

I have a java/j2ee web application built using tomcat6 and at back endI have mysql 5.1 database, I have configured my server that an amazon ec2 instance and I have installed apache tomcat6 along with mysql5.1 and also java6. I have .war file of my project. So what should I do where should I place those war files ??

Kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually in the webapps folder of the tomcat instance. By default there is also a web app called ROOT so look for that folder and put the app in the folder above ROOT. Read the tomcat docs to enable the manager application (you need to edit users XML file to create manager role user and password). Then go to the manager URL and it will let you upload your war. You should then see where it is deploying it on disk.